# NextJS - Can I build a system that would be using the path or the query parameter?

Tags: javascript, next.js

For legacy reason, I need to support a blog link that would look like `/blog?article=id-of-article`. I would like to support pre-rendering using NextJS and have blog url being `/blog/id-of-article`.

What would be the best way to support this use case ? I could do a permanent redirect or make sure both URLs render the same page. I am new with NextJS and not sure how to proceed.

Thank you !

Comment: You could use a rewrite engine to redirect `/blog?article=$1` to `/blog/$1` or make `/blog` without path param a page that returns a 301 redirect

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

```
//blog/index.js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    const { query } = context;
    console.log(query);

    if (query.article) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: `blog/${query.article}`
            }
        }
    }

    // normal action
    return { props: {} }
}
```

By using this code, if there is no query parameter named article, this route would run normally. But if there is, this would redirect the page to /blog/:article_id